# How to create this layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am playing around with Mono Droid and trying to implement the following layout

[image]

What type of layout would I use? Is there anything in Android like anchors and docking, like WinForms, so that this is can be somewhat independent?

This is for tablets only, and is more for my experimentation. The buttons inside of the left panel are to be repeating.

Thanks.

Comment: we are not supposed working in your place. You have to use a LinearLayout to devide (Left/right) after that add tableLayout on the Left, and Relative Layout on the right side.

Comment: @Sam when you want to add images to the project, copy it into the question itself. Then question is valid even if the link goes dead.

Comment: So, you want us to read the layout documentation and write the layout for you ? fat chance.

Comment: @Anis if you are trying to tell me that you're not doing my work for me - I am not asking you to do my work for me. I'm trying to teach myself something new?

Comment: @Teovald I am reading the layout documentation. I am asking for assistance. I specifically said "what type of layout would I use" I did not ask anyone to write the layout for me.

Comment: @Anis I don't need help with the items - I am just after assistance with the layout because I am completely new to Android. I don't even have a device, just playing with Mono Droid. The coding will be fine, it's just .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root Layout will be like This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="20dp" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="btn1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="btn2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="btn3" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

add you dymanic items as ListView on the top off Right and Left Layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Linear layout will work properly .. you can give the weight for specifying the space to capture..